# Missing pickers in specification?

Tags: material-design, datetimepicker, datepicker

I am trying to find a specification for date/time pickers in Material Design.
Has date/time pickers been removed from the Material Design specification?

I can't seem to find it, multiple implementations have links to the material.io page, which seem to be dead links.

See: https://materialdoc.com/components/pickers/

Which has a dead-link to: https://material.io/guidelines/components/pickers.html#pickers-date-pickers

Comment: Not really a UX question - probably best to ask over on the Material Design user groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the archives page for an older version of the specification: https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/pickers.html#pickers-date-pickers

Date/Time pickers do not seem to be in the current version of the guides.

Comment: Thanks, that page was well hidden ;)